# Saving strategy with a many to many relation when a table association is used

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have this structure of class

```
CarElementClasses
    Integer id
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carElementClass")
    private List<CarClassJoins> carClassJoins;

CarClassJoins
    Integer id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_element_class_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private CarElementClasses carElementClass;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_param_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private CarParams carParam;
    private String default;

CarParams
    Integer id
    String name
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carParam")
    private List<CarClassJoins> carClassJoins;
```

CarElementClasses has a many to many relation to carParams, CarClassJoins is a table association.

When `CarElementClasses` is displayed, user can modify, delete a `CarClassJoins`.

I don't know how to manage save, if user add and delete value.

From client side,

when a new one is added,  id of `CarClassJoins` is null... but one of user want to delete is not sent.

I need to do my save on the `CarElementClasses`.
Is there a strategy in jpa to recreate automaticly all element of the relation every time?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.

```
CarElementClasses
    Integer id
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carElementClass", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CarClassJoins> carClassJoins;

CarClassJoins
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_element_class_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private CarElementClasses carElementClass;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_param_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private CarParams carParam;
    private String default;
```

The cascade option will chain the operation made to the entity down to the related entity. For mor information: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading

The @ID and @GeneratedValue combination will generate the id when the entity persists.